# Why are there different configurations on number pads?

Tags: layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do numpads on keyboards and phones have reversed layouts?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16666/why-do-numpads-on-keyboards-and-phones-have-reversed-layouts)

So, number pads are everywhere; on you phone, keyboard, calculator, and even smart phones given the right context.  My question, why are there different layouts when it comes to the Number pad?  More specificly, there seems to be two configurations:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
   0
```

vs

```
7  8  9
4  5  6
1  2  3
0
```

**So, what advantage does one provide over the other?**

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16666/why-do-numpads-on-keyboards-and-phones-have-reversed-layouts

Comment: You're asking the exact same thing as [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16666/why-do-numpads-on-keyboards-and-phones-have-reversed-layouts) right?

Comment: And this one http://superuser.com/questions/382640/why-are-the-numbers-on-keyboard-numpads-are-not-arranged-like-atm-or-phone-keypa

Comment: Arrrg!  I guess I didn't use the correct search string to see if there were duplicates.  Sry m8s.

Comment: See also https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15611/1932 .

Answer (score 1):

The `0` in the second example offers more room for the thumb to strike, similar to a keyboard spacebar, although a keyboard spacebar is designed for both the right and left thumb.

In the second example, it is usually optimized for right hand use only. Also, imagine placing your index finger on the upper left numerical key and your thumb on the `0` simultaneously; the second feels a lot more natural and less of a reach.

Also, I've never seen the first layout before as far as number order for a 10 key.