# Why are the numbers on a calculator sorted descending and on a phone dail pad sorted ascending?

Tags: usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do numpads on keyboards and phones have reversed layouts?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16666/why-do-numpads-on-keyboards-and-phones-have-reversed-layouts)

If you look at the layout of a calculator the numbers are always sorted like this:

[image]

Most phone dail pads the numbers are sorted starting with 1

[image]

**Does anyone know why?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Used Google, this is what I found: http://www.vcalc.net/Keyboard.htm